# WooCommerce: set featured product as false when sold

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to add a snippet on my WooCommerce to remove a product from being featured when it is sold.

I tried the code below but it doesn't seem to work. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```php
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'order_status_processing_featured_products', 10, 2);
function order_status_processing_featured_products( $order_id, $order ) {
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        $product = $item->get_product();
        $product->set_featured(false);
        $product->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the hook you use is not used with every order that is created, a hook that is always used anyway is `woocommerce_thankyou`.

So you get: (Explanation via comments in the code attached)

```php
function action_woocommerce_thankyou( $order_id ) {
    // Get $order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_key => $item ) {
        // The WC_Product object
        $product = wc_get_product( $item['product_id'] );
            
        // Instanceof
        if ( $product instanceof WC_Product ) {
            // True
            if ( $product->get_featured() ) {               
                // Set featured false
                $product->set_featured( false );
                
                // Save
                $product->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'action_woocommerce_thankyou', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Thank you. that clears things up and your code works beautifully.